# Watch changes on google document time took to call a web hook

Tags: google-drive-api, c#-2.0, google-drive-realtime-api

What is the time taken to invoke a web hook call on update of google document that set a watch on folder

Comment: there is no documented time mentioned in the [docs](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/push).

Comment: Yes it is not documented but still want to know is there any time interval for trigger because i am unable to find the time it use to trigger